# powerbi rankx doesnt bring accurate values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 5 product categories and i want to rank them from 1 to 5 according to their sales but the data integrity is not accurate 100% and I would like to ask for some help.

This is my dax function for the Sum:

```
SumOrders = CALCULATE(IF(ISBLANK(SUM(FactOrders[Total])), 0, SUM(FactOrders[Total])))
```

Rankx dax:

```
Sales Amount Product Category Rank =
RANKX ( ALL ( dimProducts[Category_Name]), [SumOrders],, DESC )
```

`Store Rank Text = [Sales Amount Product Category Rank] & " of " & 5`
this is the full display of the ranks

[image]

when I will pick components and clothing both of them will have rank 3

[image]

[image]

how can I solve this issue?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Unable to replicate your issue, can you share a sample PBIX?